# Cast Enum to IEnumerable byte

Tags: c#, enums, casting, compact-framework, ienumerable

Given the following Enum

```
enum MyEnum {
   MyVal1 = 0x0000,
   MyVal2 = 0xF0F0,
   MyVal3 = 0x1234
}
```

I want to write a method returning an IEnumerable for a given Enum.

```
IEnumerable<byte> Foo(MyEnum myEnum){
     //...
}
```

So that

```
byte[] bytes = Foo(MyEnum.MyVal1).ToArray(); //bytes == 0x0000
byte[] bytes = Foo(MyEnum.MyVal2).ToArray(); //bytes == 0xF0F0
byte[] bytes = Foo(MyEnum.MyVal3).ToArray(); //bytes == 0x1234
```

Please advice. I'm on Compact Framework 3.5

Comment: Why the `Foo` returns `IEnumerable`? not `byte[]`?

Comment: It's not very clear what you want here.  What would you expect to be returned for `MyVal2` and `MyVal3`, given their values are greater than 255?

Comment: Since I might query the result with linq again. But that is not the hard part. if you know a solution returning byte[] I can also live with it.

Comment: @CharlesMager that is exactly why I need two bytes. one byte would been an easy cast. var myByte = (byte) myEnum; but it does not work for myBytes = (byte[]) myEnum;

Comment: In that case, you might want to try `System.BitConverter.GetBytes`. It is quite handy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you could use built-in `BitConverter.GetBytes` for that purpose:

```
IEnumerable<byte> Foo(MyEnum myEnum) {          
    return BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)myEnum);           
}
```

Probably the only key you want to note here is to cast your `enum` to, in this case, `ushort`, since your `enum` is 2 bytes.

Also, note that the result will be by default following `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` property. If it is `true`, then the result is little endian and if it is `false` the result is big endian.